# bionic non-live ISO

Tags: system-installation, 18.04

I can not seem to find any source for Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic ISOs that isn't a live CD.  I've been made to understand the live CD does not support preseeding ([unattended Bionic server install - set language](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036783/unattended-bionic-server-install-set-language)).

Where do I find the non-live ISO image for Bionic?  Is there one?  Did Canonical abandon this?  Am I correct that I can't preseed with a live ISO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me a while to find.  There's no link from the Ubuntu downloads page that I can find, but I found the traditional ISOs here: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/releases/18.04/release/