# Ubuntu18.04 unattended install stuck at "Welcome/Language selection"

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, kernel

I am trying to install Ubuntu18.04 with the preseed file  downloaded from http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/.

But unfortunately, it stuck at 'welcome/language selection' screen like below:

[image]

Here is the changed `isolinux.cfg` file which locate the preseed file:

```
default live
label live
  menu label ^Try Ubuntu without installing
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz
  append  file=/cdrom/unattended.seed auto=true priority=critical debian-installer/locale=en_US keyboard-configuration/layoutcode=us languagechooser/language-name=English countrychooser/shortlist=US localechooser/supported-locales=en_US.UTF-8 boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd quiet splash noprompt noshell ---
```

and the preseed file:

```
d-i preseed/early_command string tail -f /var/log/syslog > /dev/hvc0 &
d-i    debian-installer/locale         string en_US
d-i    console-keymaps-at/keymap    select us
d-i keyboard-configuration/xkb-keymap select us
d-i console-setup/ask_detect boolean false
d-i console-setup/layoutcode string us
d-i console-setup/modelcode string SKIP


d-i netcfg/choose_interface select eth0


d-i mirror/file/directory string /cdrom
d-i    mirror/http/proxy        string 
d-i    debian-installer/allow_unauthenticated    string true
d-i apt-setup/backports boolean false
d-i    time/zone string        string UTC
d-i    partman-auto/method        string regular

d-i    partman-auto/choose_recipe select atomic
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true


d-i    partman/confirm_write_new_label    boolean true
d-i    partman/choose_partition         select Finish partitioning and write 
changes to disk
d-i    partman/confirm            boolean true
d-i    passwd/make-user        boolean false
d-i passwd/root-login boolean true
d-i passwd/root-password-crypted    password 


popularity-contest    popularity-contest/participate    boolean    false
tasksel    tasksel/first            multiselect standard
d-i pkgsel/include string openssh-server psmisc patch build-essential flex 
bc python net-tools
d-i    grub-installer/only_debian    boolean true
d-i    finish-install/reboot_in_progress    note
d-i    debian-installer/exit/poweroff    boolean true
d-i preseed/late_command string sed -ri 's/^#?PermitRootLogin prohibit- 
password/PermitRootLogin yes/g' /target/etc/ssh/sshd_config; 
/target/etc/init.d/ssh restart; sed -i 's/quiet splash 
$vt_handoff/console=hvc0 console=tty0/g' /target/boot/grub/grub.cfg;
```

I read this  [link](https://github.com/hiragashi/ubuntu-unattended-install)
if stuck at welcome it maybe needs to add to preseed like below:

```
d-i grub-installer/bootdev  string /dev/sda
```

But still stuck at welcome.

Any suggestions will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You are using the Live DVD and automation does not work (27/11/2018) you need to use the non-Live DVD.  http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04/release/

I had exactly the same issue until i saw this https://askubuntu.com/a/1037088/497218

For those that are not sure:  The Live DVD has the kernel @ /casper/vmlinuz where as the non-Live DVD has it at /install/vmlinuz - you would see this in your txt.cfg file.

Comment: Thanks, it works after I changed to the non-live DVD. :)